# JQuery window.resize not working just reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to adjust the page so that it does not scroll regardless of the device, it works at all, however, when you rotate the screen or when you change the device to inspect Google Chrome, the function does not work, only if I do the reload on the page that works, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, that's what I'm calling her

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    changesize();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        changesize();
    });
};
```

Comment: We need to see the code for `changesize`, the example code works as it is. Not exactly related, but you might want to listen `orientationchage` event in mobiles, some mobile browsers are changing the size of the addressbar depending on the scrolling position, and that triggers a resize event. Depending on what `changesize` function does, it might be very annoying UX.

Comment: Agreed, it sounds like it might be a timing issue. If we could see the code for ``changesize()`` it may assist in sorting your issue. Another way you can see whether ``.resize`` function is working is add a ``console.log()`` message and see if it fires at all, if it does - then it is definitely your ``changesize()`` function.

Answer (score 0):

It is a syntax error document ready function closing bracket missing. Please refer below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    changesize();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        changesize();
    });
});
```

Comment: OP says, that the function works on page refresh, hence the lack of the closing parenthese is probably a typo in the post only.

Answer (score 0):

I think this piece of code should fix your problem. It should trigger the resize function as needed when you flip your device. Let me know if it works :

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
}, false);
```